# MongoDB lookup reference (inverse)

Tags: mongodb, reference, lookup, aggregation

I am using MongoDB server version: 4.2.6.
I have two collections.

Users and Hobbies

```
USER
{
    "_id": "ABC123",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}

SERVICES
{
    "_id": "9999CCB",
    "description": "10 Mbps Internet",
    "user": "ABC123" 
}, 

How do I build an aggregation pipeline with $lookup to query provide the services from the Users collection?
```

The following code does not work because there is no reference to the Services collection in Users, but is it somehow still possible to query?

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "services",
      "localField": "null",    // <----- THERE IS NO REFERENCE IN THE USER COLLECTION TO SERVICES
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "services"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$services",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  }
]
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Essentially I would like to achieve the following result:

```
{
  "_id": "ABC123",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "services": {
    "_id": "9999CCB",
    "description": "10 Mbps Internet",
    "user": "ABC123"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out.  Turns out it is as simple as using the local document's _id in the localField:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "services",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user",
      "as": "services"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$services",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  }
]
```